# Passing the Interface type for casting as parameter

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a function that calls another one using Generics.
Now i would like to pass the type for the inner function as a parameter to the outer one:

```
void MyFunction()
{
    CallFunction<ISomeInterface>(); //  here ISomeInterface should be a parameter to MyFunction
}
```

I already tried with `<T>` and `typeof` and `Type` but without success.

edit:
tried:

`void MyFunction<T>()`

`void MyFunction(Type type)`

`CallFunction<typeof(parameter)>();`

Comment: Can you show CallFunction as well and tell us what error did you get why it is not working? Without success doesn't help.

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is make `MyFunction` generic and pass the type parameter to the called method:

```
void MyFunction<T>()
{
    CallFunction<T>();
}
```

Then you can call it using:

```
MyFunction<ISomeInterface>();
```

---

**Edit:** `CallFunction` seems to have a constraint on its type parameter. `MyFunction` needs to have the same constraints:

If you have

```
CallFunction<T>() where T : class { /* .. */ }
```

Then

```
void MyFunction<T>() where T : class { /* .. */ }
```

Comment: already tried that, but gives me the compile error: `
Error CS0452 The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'CallFunction<T>()`

Answer (score -1):

You need to do some reflection like this:

```
void Main()
{
    MyFunction(typeof(Foo));
}

void MyFunction(Type someType)
{
    var method =
        this
            .GetType()
            .GetMethod(
                "CallFunction",
                BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
            .MakeGenericMethod(someType);

    method.Invoke(this, null);
}

void CallFunction<T>()
{
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(T).Name);
}

public class Foo { }
```

That outputs `Foo` to the console.